# Recursive Sorting: quick sort syntax

Tags: java, syntax, syntax-error, quicksort

The programs should sort a set of a number using a quick sort. Use Data Sets Starting at 10,000,000 randomly generated numbers. I've been learning about quicksort. Another, I finished merge sort. However, the quicksort is syntax. I don't know why it's syntax.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        for(int n = 1; n<=100; n++)
        {// begin for
            int size = 10000000; //change this num to change the size of the random array 10,000,000

            int[] a = new int[size];
            int[] temp = new int[a.length]; //temporary array, it's empty.

            //fill the array with random integers
            for(int i = 0; i< a.length; i++)
                a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100000 + 1);

            long startTime = System.nanoTime();

            quickSort(a, temp, 0,(a.length - 1));

            long endTime = System.nanoTime();

            long duration = endTime - startTime;

            System.out.printf("%12.8f %n", (double)duration/100000000);


        }// End for
    }// end main

    public static void quickSort(int[] a, int[] temp, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {// begin quickSort
        int pivotIndex; //the index of pivot returned by the quciksort partition

        if(startIndex < endIndex)
        {//Begin if
            pivotIndex = partition(a, temp, startIndex, endIndex);

            quickSort(a, temp, startIndex, pivotIndex -1);
            quickSort(a, temp, pivotIndex+1, endIndex);
        }//End if
    }//end quickSort

    public static int partition(int[] a, int[] temp, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        int pivotIndex;
        int pivot;
        int midIndex = startIndex;

        pivotIndex = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2;
        pivot = a[pivotIndex];

        swap(a, temp, pivotIndex, endIndex);

        for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
            if (a[i] < pivot) ;
            {
                swap(a, temp, i, midIndex);
                midIndex = midIndex + 1;
            }
        }
        swap(a, temp, midIndex, endIndex);
        return midIndex;
    }// end partition

    public  static void swap(int[]a, int[]temp, int first, int second)
    {//Begin swap
        for(int i = first; i <= second; i++){
            temp[i] = a[i];
        }
        int c;

        c = a[first];
        a[first] = a[second];
        a[second] = c;
    }//End swap

    public static void writeLines(int[] a, String fileName) throws Exception
    {  // Begin writeLines(int[] a, String fileName)

        // create a File class object with the given file name
        java.io.File out = new java.io.File(fileName);
        // Create a PrintWriter output stream and link it to the File object
        java.io.PrintWriter outfile = new java.io.PrintWriter(out);

        // write the elements of an int array, separated by spaces
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {   // Begin for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)

            outfile.print(a[i] + " ");

        }   // End for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)

        // print a newline at the end of the list of integers

        outfile.println();

        outfile.close();

    } // End writeLines(int[] a, String fileName) throws Exception


}//end quickSORT
```

I got syntax. It said quick.partition and quick.quickSort.

Comment: I am used IntelliJ IDEA Java

Comment: What do you mean when you say the word "syntax"? Are you asking how quicksort works?

Comment: hello @CaiusJard, yes, I am asking how quicksort works?

Comment: Quicksort is an in-place sort. It does not require/use an auxiliary array (your `temp` here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple terms, Hoare's quicksort works by:

- having an array of data
- picking some middle element
- logically dividing the array into 3 categories:

  - everything to the left of the middle element - we'll call this the lower section
  - the middle element
  - everything to the right of the middle element - we'll call this the upper section
- remembering the value at the middle element
- starting from the very left of the lower section looking for a value that is greater than the middle element, or in other words it tries to find something that shouldn't be in the lower section because it is too big
- when it finds one it starts from the right hand side of the upper section looking for an element that is "too small for the upper section"
- if values are found that meet these criteria, they're swapped over
- this happens repeatedly until everything that is too big for the lower section has been transferred into the upper section and everything too small for the upper section has been transferred into the lower section
- the result is a "partly sorted" array; everything to the left of the middle element is smaller than it and everything to the right of the middle element is larger than it
- the algorithm starts over, this time treating just the lower section as if it was the entire array, then it does the same with the upper section
- by taking the whole, then halving it, then quartering it, then... you reach a point where you're just making sure that a bunch of pairs or single elements are sorted, and then that's all done

Your algorithm uses something like a mix of the Hoare and Lomuto partitioning strategies but mostly more like Lomuto. There are various strategies for partitioning (choosing how to divide the array into sections) depending on things like how the data container works (Hoare's strategy requires containers that can be randomly accessed or accessed from each end, like a double linked list, Lomuto only needs a data container to be readable in one direction) but quicksort's basic algorithm is this notion that you split everything into two piles of "want smaller values" and "want larger values", swap things repeatedly between the piles until "smaller" and "larger" really is true, then do the process again first to the smaller pile, then the larger pile. If you keep going and dividing the work then you reach a point where everything is sorted.

If you're still struggling with it, maybe consider instead: If you think of it like sorting a large amount of words that only use the characters A and Z, into alphabetical order you might have a strategy of putting everything into piles: 2 piles of those that start with A and those that start with Z. Then you make 4 piles, those that start AA, AZ, ZA and ZZ. Then you move to 8 piles of three letters AAA, AAZ, AZA, AZZ, ZAA, ZAZ, ZZA and ZZZ (which is probably appropriate if you're asleep by now ).  This is also a "divide and conquer strategy"; you'll reach a point where you've divided the piles so much that they each only contain one thing, then if you gather piles up in order (and if you've been careful when you laid them out they will already be in order) then they are sorted

Oh, and your code has an error in that you've added a semicolon after an if, which creates an empty statement (makes the if useless), and you also don't seem to use the temp array you carry around. It's like this algo was hoping to be a blend of two different sort strategies but is unfinished

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I just have figured out to write my quick sort project.